# onCreate Override function not call?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

When we call AppCompatActivity method from activity lifecycle override onActivityStarted method
then appcompact activity oncreate not call.

```
DemoActivity().addactvity(activity)
```

Here DemoActivity is AppCompatActivity

How to call DemoActivity onCreate Method?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? Please elaborate.

Comment: @SujalKumar we need call DemoActivity() without startActivity() or startActivityForResult() .

We call DemoActivity with DemoActivity().addactvity(activity).

but when we call this then DemoActivity oncreate() method not work.

Is There any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

You are not supposed to instantiate activities yourself like you are doing with `DemoActivity()`.

Instead you should let the framework instantiate the activity and follow up with appropriate lifecycle function calls such as `onCreate()`. To instruct the framework to launch an activity this way, use `startActivity()` (or `startActivityForResult()`) from a `Context`.

Comment: Thanks for Comment. but we need to all my DemoActivity() oncreate method without use startActivity() or startActivityForResult() these. is this possible?

Comment: No, it won't be useful for anything you would need an activity for.